# JQGrid: Cutting and pasting in a filter toolbar does not trigger filtering

Tags: search, jqgrid, toolbar

I have exactly the same experience as reported in [the JQGrid forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/cutting-and-pasting-in-a-filter-toolbar-does-not-trigger-filtering/).

If I copy and paste some text via the mouse into a search field (i.e. right click, "paste"), a search is not triggered. If I copy and paste via the keyboard (e.g. Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V), then the search is triggered.

I.e. it seems that search is triggered on keypress/keyup only - how can I configure the grid to recognize mouse paste events as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options you could try.

**Option 1:**

You could set your toolbar to search on enter only by setting the option: searchOnEnter to true when setting up your toolbar. This will require enter to be clicked before the filter will happen, regardless of how it is entered

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{ searchOnEnter: true });
```

**Option2: (Updated to fix errors)**

Detect a paste event with jQuery and then call the api to trigger a toolbar search.

```
var headers = $('.ui-th-column');
$.each(headers, function(index, item) {
     var div = $(this).children('div');
     if (div.length > 0) {
         var input = div.children('input');
         if (input.length > 0) {
             $(input).bind('paste', function(e) {
                  var sgrid = $("#grid_id")[0];
                  sgrid.triggerToolbar();
              });
         }
     }
});
```

*note: it does not appear that there is a way to trigger the search using the new api.*

Comment: I prefer to not use option 1 (searchONEnter: true)

Comment: Marking this as the correct because my answer using dataInit messes up the advanced search dialog if you're using it. Note that I still had to add the setTimeout call to make this work

Answer (score 1):

I think I've cracked it. You can add a "paste" event in the "dataEvents" array in searchOptions:

```
var colModel = [...,
    searchoptions: {
        dataEvents: [
                       { type: 'paste',  
                         fn: function(e) { 
                           setTimeout(function() {
                             var sgrid = $("#grid_id")[0]; 
                             sgrid.triggerToolbar();
                           }, 1);   
                         }  
                       }
                    ]}
];
```

**Note the setTimeout call** - I found it necessary to add, otherwise the search gets triggered without the pasted value

This solution achieves more or less the same thing as option 2 proposed by @fbfcn , but I like it better since it ties in cleaner with the API.

Comments appreciated!

Comment: +1 yes much cleaner and does not require all the selectors I had to do.

Comment: Argg.... the problem with this solution is that it then triggers a toolbar search when you paste values into the textfield of the advanced search search form - not the behaviour I want.